# One node module, two libraries, one export in ES6

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

For the time being, until the library is split into JS frameworks specific repos (React, JQuery, Angular, etc.), I have multiple libraries within one npm module (yes, that right there is an anti-pattern).

But humor me, how do I export one of the libraries without exporting the other? I don't want the jquery module if I'm just using React and there is only one "main" in `package.json`.

One option would be to import the module via relative directory that is `from './node_modules/ui-combined-module/src/react/dist.js';`, but that seems rather messy.

For

```
// Use one of the following in your example code:
// import {react as UILibraryReact} from 'ui-combined-module';
// const Badge = UILibraryReact.Badge;

// import {jquery as UILibraryJquery} from 'ui-combined-module';
// const Badge = UILibraryJquery.Badge;

import * as react from './react/dist';
import * as jquery from './jquery/dist';

module.exports = {
    react,
    jquery
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not import jquery or react in the code using this module?

```
import react from 'yourlib'
```

Or return a function

```
exports default function (lib) {
   if(lib === 'react') return react;
   ...
}
```

Comment: I think above your `export` statement you would still need to import BOTH react and jquery modules otherwise you can't return them, because they won't be defined.

Comment: I suppose you could replace `react` with the older require syntax `if(lib === 'react') return require('react')`